# SQL Query conversion to Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, join, orm, django-orm

```
select
    l.student_id,
    SUM(l.sum_result)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            w.student_id,
            w.subject_id,
            r.total as sum_result
        from
            Student w
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(r.id) as total,
                    r.subject_fk_id
                from
                    Result r
                GROUP BY
                    r.subject_fk_id
            ) r ON w.subject_id = r.subject_fk_id
    ) l
GROUP BY
    student_id
```

```
The tables are:

Student
-------------
-> id(PK)
->student_name
->student_email


Subject
--------------
-> id(PK)
-> subject_name


Results
---------------
->id (PK)
->subject_fk(FK to subject table)
->date
```

there is one many to many table for student and subject

```
Student_Subject
->id(PK)
->Student_id(FK)
->Subject_id(FK)
```

I want to convert this SQL query to Django ORM
I need to retreive the total number of results for a Student. I need to write this query in Django
ORM without for loops. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

your query missing a relationship part , also you can simplify your query to this :

```
select s.student_id,count(r.id)
from students s 
Join student_subject ss 
 on ss.studentid = s.studentid
join subject sb
 on sb.subject_id = ss.subject_id
join result r
 on r.ssid = ss.id 
group by s.student_id
```

so now I think you can write equivalent ORM yourself easily , right ? ;)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, there is nothing like Students in subject table. In Django there is one field defined in Subject table called Student_Subject which has many to many relationship with Student table. So a table is created with Student_Subject name

Comment: So one more join . Still simple query